# What electrical contact material is used for PF Connectors?

Tags: power-functions, manufacturing, customization

[image]

I'm designing my own PF electrical connector and I want to have the same functional characteristics as the original Lego brick.

Could you please let me know which electrical contact material is used in the original brick?

Comment: I don't know the specific material, but it's likely nickle or aluminum.  You can't go wrong with those.  If you want to the best material, you would probably want to look into plating.

Comment: Or buy an [extension cable](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/LEGO-Power-Functions-Extension-Wire-20-8871) and cut it in half.

Comment: How is your design going? I'd be very interested in purchasing a large quantity of a PCB (SMD or thru-hole) version of this connector. Philbot.

Comment: I hope to have a tested samples in 5-6 weeks. Will let you know when I have it.

Comment: how are the samples doing?

Answer (score 2):

The material is most likely aluminum or tinned copper, here is why:

Most LEGOs are made in Denmark, the country of origin, with other various quantities made in mexico, Taiwan, and other factories around the world. Denmark is a huge exporter of electrical generators (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Denmark#/media/File:Denmark_Export_Treemap.jpg)). Making generators requires a good amount of aluminum and copper to make, especially if the generator has a build in power transmission. I would be willing to bet that the same materials that are available to make generators would also be available to make LEGOs, copper and aluminum. I'm leaning towards tinned copper because of the luster in the pictures, but I couldn't tell you for sure, and LEGO doesn't provide a datasheet.